# Кроссплатформенная отправка на печать файла

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Платформа .NET Core 2.1.
Необходима поддержка систем:

- CentOs 7
- Windows 7 и старше

Задача:
 Отправка на печать файлов разного формата(rtf, pdf, doc, odt).
В линукс есть подсистема CUPS через которую можно отправлять на печать файлы очень легко по имени принтера и файла. Аналогичная команда для винды (print) по сути не работает и у клиента настройками заниматься будет невозможно. 
В линукс можно получить список принтеров, потом по имени отправить на печать, есть ли что-то аналогичное в винде. В самой .NET библиотеке ничего похожего не нашел. System.Drawing.Prinitng, только для вин форм как я понимаю и печать там построчная, с указанием шрифта. Приложение десктопное

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/lpr

Comment: Решил проблему. В рантайме выбираю что необходимо и если необходима виндовая версия то использую RawPrint библиотеку иначе через баш отправляю на CUPS в линуксе отправку PDF файла.